# What happens when we call puppeteer waitForSelector API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, devtools

This question is based on Puppeteer and headless Chrome interaction (based on chrome devtools protocol).

Puppeteer sends JSON formatted messages to Chrome devtools to control chrome operations like accessing a page, typing in a textfield or click a button etc.

When we execute below line (this helps to wait till #username is visible)

```
await page.waitForSelector('#username', { visible: true });
```

Puppeteer sends below 5 messages to Chrome.

```
{"sessionId":"EB950D87CE0E2EED6D432F080811B87D","method":"Runtime.callFunctionOn","params":{"functionDeclaration":"async function waitForPredicatePageFunction(predicateBody, polling, timeout, ...args) {\n  const predicate = new Function('...args', predicateBody);\n  let timedOut = false;\n  if (timeout)\n    setTimeout(() => timedOut = true, timeout);\n  if (polling === 'raf')\n    return await pollRaf();\n  if (polling === 'mutation')\n    return await pollMutation();\n  if (typeof polling === 'number')\n    return await pollInterval(polling);\n\n  /**\n   * @return {!Promise<*>}\n   */\n  function pollMutation() {\n    const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\n    if (success)\n      return Promise.resolve(success);\n\n    let fulfill;\n    const result = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);\n    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {\n      if (timedOut) {\n        observer.disconnect();\n        fulfill();\n      }\n      const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\n      if (success) {\n        observer.disconnect();\n        fulfill(success);\n      }\n    });\n    observer.observe(document, {\n      childList: true,\n      subtree: true,\n      attributes: true\n    });\n    return result;\n  }\n\n  /**\n   * @return {!Promise<*>}\n   */\n  function pollRaf() {\n    let fulfill;\n    const result = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);\n    onRaf();\n    return result;\n\n    function onRaf() {\n      if (timedOut) {\n        fulfill();\n        return;\n      }\n      const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\n      if (success)\n        fulfill(success);\n      else\n        requestAnimationFrame(onRaf);\n    }\n  }\n\n  /**\n   * @param {number} pollInterval\n   * @return {!Promise<*>}\n   */\n  function pollInterval(pollInterval) {\n    let fulfill;\n    const result = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);\n    onTimeout();\n    return result;\n\n    function onTimeout() {\n      if (timedOut) {\n        fulfill();\n        return;\n      }\n      const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\n      if (success)\n        fulfill(success);\n      else\n        setTimeout(onTimeout, pollInterval);\n    }\n  }\n}\n//# sourceURL=__puppeteer_evaluation_script__\n","executionContextId":4,"arguments":[{"value":"return (function predicate(selectorOrXPath, isXPath, waitForVisible, waitForHidden) {\n      const node = isXPath\n        ? document.evaluate(selectorOrXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue\n        : document.querySelector(selectorOrXPath);\n      if (!node)\n        return waitForHidden;\n      if (!waitForVisible && !waitForHidden)\n        return node;\n      const element = /** @type {Element} */ (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? node.parentElement : node);\n\n      const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);\n      const isVisible = style && style.visibility !== 'hidden' && hasVisibleBoundingBox();\n      const success = (waitForVisible === isVisible || waitForHidden === !isVisible);\n      return success ? node : null;\n\n      /**\n       * @return {boolean}\n       */\n      function hasVisibleBoundingBox() {\n        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();\n        return !!(rect.top || rect.bottom || rect.width || rect.height);\n      }\n    })(...args)"},{"value":"raf"},{"value":30000},{"value":"#username"},{"value":false},{"value":true},{"value":false}],"returnByValue":false,"awaitPromise":true,"userGesture":true},"id":28}

---------------

{"sessionId":"EB950D87CE0E2EED6D432F080811B87D","method":"Runtime.callFunctionOn","params":{"functionDeclaration":"s => !s\n//# sourceURL=__puppeteer_evaluation_script__\n","executionContextId":4,"arguments":[{"objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":4,\"id\":3}"}],"returnByValue":true,"awaitPromise":true,"userGesture":true},"id":29}

-------------

{"sessionId":"EB950D87CE0E2EED6D432F080811B87D","method":"DOM.describeNode","params":{"objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":4,\"id\":3}"},"id":30}

-------------

{"sessionId":"EB950D87CE0E2EED6D432F080811B87D","method":"DOM.resolveNode","params":{"backendNodeId":11,"executionContextId":3},"id":31}

-------------

{"sessionId":"EB950D87CE0E2EED6D432F080811B87D","method":"Runtime.releaseObject","params":{"objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":4,\"id\":3}"},"id":32}
```

I am trying to understand whats happening here. The 1st message looks a javascript function. Is this Javascript function gets executed at hesdless chrome.

Basically I need to understand clearly whats happening when **waitForSelector** is executed.

**EDIT**
The javascript function if I extract from first JSON messages looks as below.

```
async function waitForPredicatePageFunction(predicateBody, polling, timeout, ...args) {\
  const predicate = new Function('...args', predicateBody);\
  let timedOut = false;\
  if (timeout)\
    setTimeout(() => timedOut = true, timeout);\
  if (polling === 'raf')\
    return await pollRaf();\
  if (polling === 'mutation')\
    return await pollMutation();\
  if (typeof polling === 'number')\
    return await pollInterval(polling);\
\
  /**\
   * @return {!Promise<*>}\
   */\
  function pollMutation() {\
    const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\
    if (success)\
      return Promise.resolve(success);\
\
    let fulfill;\
    const result = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);\
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {\
      if (timedOut) {\
        observer.disconnect();\
        fulfill();\
      }\
      const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\
      if (success) {\
        observer.disconnect();\
        fulfill(success);\
      }\
    });\
    observer.observe(document, {\
      childList: true,\
      subtree: true,\
      attributes: true\
    });\
    return result;\
  }\
\
  /**\
   * @return {!Promise<*>}\
   */\
  function pollRaf() {\
    let fulfill;\
    const result = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);\
    onRaf();\
    return result;\
\
    function onRaf() {\
      if (timedOut) {\
        fulfill();\
        return;\
      }\
      const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\
      if (success)\
        fulfill(success);\
      else\
        requestAnimationFrame(onRaf);\
    }\
  }\
\
  /**\
   * @param {number} pollInterval\
   * @return {!Promise<*>}\
   */\
  function pollInterval(pollInterval) {\
    let fulfill;\
    const result = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);\
    onTimeout();\
    return result;\
\
    function onTimeout() {\
      if (timedOut) {\
        fulfill();\
        return;\
      }\
      const success = predicate.apply(null, args);\
      if (success)\
        fulfill(success);\
      else\
        setTimeout(onTimeout, pollInterval);\
    }\
  }\
}\
//# sourceURL=__puppeteer_evaluation_script__\
```

And in argument list I see below arguments

```
return (function predicate(selectorOrXPath, isXPath, waitForVisible, waitForHidden) {\
      const node = isXPath\
        ? document.evaluate(selectorOrXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue\
        : document.querySelector(selectorOrXPath);\
      if (!node)\
        return waitForHidden;\
      if (!waitForVisible && !waitForHidden)\
        return node;\
      const element = /** @type {Element} */ (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? node.parentElement : node);\
\
      const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);\
      const isVisible = style && style.visibility !== 'hidden' && hasVisibleBoundingBox();\
      const success = (waitForVisible === isVisible || waitForHidden === !isVisible);\
      return success ? node : null;\
\
      /**\
       * @return {boolean}\
       */\
      function hasVisibleBoundingBox() {\
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();\
        return !!(rect.top || rect.bottom || rect.width || rect.height);\
      }\
    })(...args)
```

Then other arguments I see

raf

3000

username

false

true

false

These are all information. I am not able to relate altogether what is happening. Can you please explain in detail whats going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`waitFor`s in Puppeteer are being solved using polling. `waitForSelector` uses the `raf` option for polling:

> raf: constantly execute pageFunction in requestAnimationFrame callback. This is the tightest polling mode which is suitable to observe styling changes.

So, basically. `waitForSelector` will send a function that will run on each `requestAnimationFrame`. That function will resolve a promise when the selector is visible (or hidden, depending on your options), or when it timeouts.

When that function is serialized and sent to Chromium this is what would happen:

- `waitForPredicatePageFunction` will be executed.
- As the `polling` method will be `raf`, it will await `pollRaf`.
- `pollRaf` will execute the function it got as an argument, in this case, a `selector` check.
- If false will return a promise.
- It will call itself calling `requestAnimationFrame`.
- It will loop until the predicate returns true or it timeouts.

Comment: I have edited my question, with further details. Request if you can explain me whats actually happening. I know javascript, basic level only.

Comment: @Austin, I don't get what you want to know.

Comment: We have one javascript function waitForPredicatePageFunction. The argument predicateBody in that looks another Javascript function. Which one is executed, or both are executed. I see other functions called like requestAnimationFrame(onRaf); fulfill(); where are these defined. May be it is my poor JS knowledge I am not getting it in entirety.  If you can edit your answer like whats getting executed sequentially it will be a great help.